# Bash Script errors when trying to grep -v -q in if statement

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to write a script that does something when the read line does not include a `*` symbol in the line.

I've tried the following with no success:

1. `if [ grep -v -q '*' ]` which results in a too many arguments error
2. `if [ "$(grep -v -q '*')" -eq '0' ];` which results in a unary operator expected error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An if statement will accept anything that produces exit status, so either a
shell builtin like `[` or `test` - or a disk file like `grep`. You can use both:

```
if [ "$(grep -c '*' file)" = 0 ]
then
  echo 'star symbol not found'
fi
```

but its really not needed:

```
if ! grep -q '*' file
then
  echo 'star symbol not found'
fi
```

Or:

```
while read x
do
  if ! grep -q '*' <<eof
$x
eof
  then
    printf '%s does not contain star symbol\n' "$x"
  fi  
done < file
```

Or:

```
awk '!/\*/ {print $0, "does not contain star symbol"}' file
```